# Accessing a variable from a separate class in Xcode

Tags: objective-c

My code has an AppDelegate, a view controller, a main view, and a separate class called Sprite.h and Sprite.m.  My mainview.m has

```
 if (!eye) {
     eye = [[Sprite alloc] initWithPic: @"eye1.png"
         frameCnt: 1
         frameStep: 1
         speed: CGPointMake(-5, 5)
         pos: CGPointMake(300, 400)];
   }
```

calls the sprite class and has it create an object which flies around the screen in various random directions.  I need to make it so that if its positions hits the player positions then he dies, but the variable for player position is in main view

Is there a way to share the location of the eye in sprite.m with main view.m?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make our variable a property in `Sprite` clas, by declaring it in Sprite.h. Then, since you have an instance of `Sprite` in main view, you can just reference it as `eye.location`.

Answer (score 0):

Your MainView.m is the parent that has child called separate class (Sprite.m). If you want to get the variable from the Sprite.m. You should declare the delegate for sprite class as the following:

```
@class Sprite;

@protocol SpriteDelegate
-(void)sprite:(Sprite*)sprite location:(CGPoint*)point;

@interface Sprite: UIView<...>{
    CGPoint* point;
    //Your variables ...
}

@property (assign) id <SpriteDelegate> delegate;
//others property ...
@end
```

In your sprite.m

```
-(void)updatePoint{ //your function when you want to send your point to mainview
     [self.delegate sprite:self location:yourPoint];
}
```

In your mainview.h, you should add the delegate

```
@interface MainView: UIView<SpriteDelegate>
```

In your mainview.m:

```
if (!eye) { 
    eye = [[Sprite alloc] initWithPic: @"eye1.png" frameCnt: 1 frameStep: 1 speed: CGPointMake(-5, 5) pos: CGPointMake(300, 400)]; 
    eye.delegate = self;
}

-(void)sprite:(Sprite*)sprite location:(CGPoint*)point{
     //Do with your point your received
}
```

Comment: the first piece of that code is meant to go in Sprite.h, Right?  i tried putting it there, but protocal gives me the error expected identifier or "(" and missing @end.  Also what do I put in Sprite:UIView<….>

Comment: Sorry, my code is no review by XCode, just manual. You could refer to: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tip-create-your-own-objective-c-delegate-protocol/ to know how to create delegate custom class